# isapi Rewrite For Just One Folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a phycical folder at /shop/cart-plugins/subscription-wizard/. To make it easier for users find I have set up the following rule in my htaccess file to turn this into /join/.

It works great if they type in www.mywebsite.com/join/, but if they don't type in the last slash mark it doesn't do anything. I've looked all over google, but can't figure it out. Any advice you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the rule I have set up.

```
RewriteRule ^shop/cart-plugins/subscription-wizard? /join/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/cart-plugins/subscription-wizard/? /join/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/cart-plugins/subscription-wizard/(.*) /join/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^join/(.*) /shop/cart-plugins/subscription-wizard/$1 [QSA]
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^join$ /join/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I spent over an hour trying to figure this out before.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it by clicking the check-mark on the left. Tnx.